# Efficient method how to realize sumif and countif in R

Tags: r, countif, sapply

When I realize countif and sumif by R, 
I always use sapply-function and table-function like this:

```
symbol = letters[sample(1:3, 5, replace=TRUE)]
df=data.frame(a=symbol,
          b=seq_len(length(symbol)))


#sumif
summary=data.frame(key=unique(df$a))
summary$sum=sapply(
  seq_len(nrow(summary)),
  function(i) with(df, sum(df$b[a==summary$key[i]]))
)

#countif
countif = data.frame(
  key=names(table(df$a)),
  count=as.vector(table(df$a))
)

summary = merge(
  summary,
  countif,
  c("key")
)
```

Is there any efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` for efficiency.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'a', we get the `sum` of 'b' and the number of elements (`.N`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(sum = sum(b), count = .N), .(key = a)]
#    key sum count
#1:   c   1     1
#2:   a   6     2
#3:   b   8     2
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(key = a) %>%
   summarise(sum = sum(b), count = .N)
```